# How to write a SQL query for normalization?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to normalize the values in my table by using the SQL query.

My table is like this:

```
id  name 
--------
1   A
1   B
1   C
2   D
2   E
```

Required a table like this:

```
id  name 
----------
1   A,B,C   
2   D, E
```

Just want to know what logic I should apply.

Comment: What you are requesting is exactly the opposite of "normalization".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [aggregate function `LISTAGG()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm):

```
SELECT id, LISTAGG(name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name) name
FROM mytable
GROUP BY id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c0b1e9c42fc475e8f687044966bf947f)**:

```
ID | NAME 
-: | :----
 1 | A,B,C
 2 | D,E
```

Comment: Thanks, @GMB.  The answer was useful.